# Console kernel option: Setting /dev/console to tty3 redirects output to the current active console

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

I am trying to understand the console= parameter provided to the kernel and doing so I have modified `/etc/default/grub` to set console up to be **tty3** such as (the reason I have chosen **tty3** as opposed to **ttyS0** is that I don't have a serial port):
[image]

I am assuming by setting up console to be **tty3** the kernel will only output messages to **tty3** and no other tty. I have entered using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> into **tty2** and pressed the key <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>SysRq</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>. If I check `dmesg` I can see the message there.

By doing that I can see the message of the kernel in the current **tty2**. By navigating to **tty3** I do not see any messages.

Just for completeness, console is configured correctly to point to **tty3**:

```
~$ cat /sys/devices/virtual/tty/console/active
tty3
```

Furthermore to this, I have compiled a generic `helloworld` module and performed insmod and rmmod on it. The output appears on the currently active **tty** and not the specified console (**tty3**).

I don't understand why this is happening. Could someone explain? Have I misunderstood the console parameter?

Comment: I suspect this is because tty3 doesn't exist at early boot time, and I mean "exist" as an allocated data structure inside the kernel, not as a node under `/dev/`. The `ttyN` devices (where N>1) are allocated on demand from userspace, I think - and at that time there is no userspace. Anyway, I also like to see messages on a VT, but I do that with syslog (`/etc/rsyslog.conf` since I use mostly Debian and derivatives). Also see the sysctl setting `kernel.printk` for a way to regulate console noise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The names that are used in the `console=` setting of the Linux command line are not device filenames that are looked up in the filesystem.  They are actually [a combination](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/8f02f363f76f99f08117336cfac7f24c76b25be3/kernel/printk/printk.c#L2201) of a *registration name* and an *index*, "tty3" being the registration name "tty" and the index 3.

The registration names are compared against the *internal names* that device drivers use to register console I/O handlers.  These need not match user-space device names at all.  "tty" matches the name used by the *kernel virtual terminal* subsystem [when it registers its console I/O handler](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/8f02f363f76f99f08117336cfac7f24c76b25be3/drivers/tty/vt/vt.c#L3023).

The index *is not* the KVT number.  It is used for matching a particular console I/O handler instance when a device driver provides *more than 1 console I/O handler* by the same name.  This is *not the case* for the KVT subsystem, which only registers one console I/O handler.  In such a case, the index is in fact largely ignored.  And this is indeed what happens with the index 3.

Yes, the Linux doco [says otherwise](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/8f02f363f76f99f08117336cfac7f24c76b25be3/Documentation/admin-guide/kernel-parameters.txt#L627).  The Linux doco *is wrong*.  Again.

Furthermore, the KVT subsystem by default writes all console output, when it has been selected as a console *in the first place*, to the *currently active* KVT.  This can be changed, but *not by* the registration index numbers used on the kernel command line in `console=` specifications.  Rather, it is changed by issuing a `TIOCL_SETKMSGREDIRECT` subcommand to the `TIOCLINUX` `ioctl()` against a KVT device (for best results, the KVT device that is being redirected *to*, otherwise the KVT may not even exist, as KVTs are not created until their device files are opened).

The Linux doco doesn't get this wrong.  It rather simply *doesn't document `TIOCL_SETKMSGREDIRECT` at all* on the `console_ioctl` manual page.

For non-programmers, this functionality is accessible via tools such as [the rather misleadingly documented Busybox `setlogcons` command](https://busybox.net/downloads/BusyBox.html#setlogcons) and [Allan Cruse's `setconsole`](https://www.cs.usfca.edu/%7Ecruse/cs635/setconsole.cpp).

## Further reading

- Jonathan de Boyne Pollard (2018). "[linux-vt](http://jdebp.uk./Softwares/nosh/guide/commands/linux-vt.xml)".  *Devices*.  nosh toolset.
- Jonathan de Boyne Pollard (2018). "[linux-console](http://jdebp.uk./Softwares/nosh/guide/commands/linux-console.xml)".  *Devices*.  nosh toolset.

Comment: One thing to add which is confusing as well is that if I do console=tty3 and then I do "init 1" (go to single user mode) tty3 is indeed the active tty. This is where the logging prompt is located.
Seems like a separate mechanism and convention is used to the kernel itself.